# Microservice Web java call jar

Tags: java, microservices

Which is more efficient?

1. A service web that proceeses the business logic over jboss/glassfish?
2. A service web that processes the business logic  by calling a java -jar o c++ file?

The web server has an assigned memory, and it distributes to all web apps. But by executing a jar file, I can assign the system memory. My app consumes a lot of memory, because of simultaneous requests, also some objects aren’t destroyed correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't try to micromanage your container efficiency until you fix your memory leaks.

Comment: you are reason , but upon the question, ¿what is your opinion?

Comment: if I understand correctly you are asking the difference between using an internal web server and external web server in terms of efficiency. Is that correct?

Comment: the difereence beteween if i call from a service web 
a) the bussines logic over myself service web
b) the bussines logic over a .jar or .exe

The bussines logic use very much thread and memory because very much open big files